# Проблема с упорядочиванием файлов

Tags: файлы, сортировка, windows-10, windows-8

Возникла проблема в упорядочивании докуметнов.

Как пример, создано несколько файлов которые упорядочены по имени в убывающем порядке (ниже изображение)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что файл с именем 'y' либо 'Y'(не имеет значения) упорядочивается после файла с именем 'i', а не после 'x'

Проблема проявляется в Windows 8.1 и в Windows 10.

Пытался менять региональные настройки и даже менять шрифты, но ничего не помогло.

Есть ли у кого нибудь идеи как это можно решить?

Comment: `dir /b /o:n` что показывает?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov показывает в таком же порядке, как и на изображении

Comment: `dir /b /o:n > out.txt` out.txt выложить (не скопировать содержимое, а выложить весь файл) куда-то на файлобменник. Есть подозрение, что Ваш `y` - нечто другое

Comment: @AntonShchyrov , Ссылка на файл http://dropmefiles.com/WF5uo

Comment: Прикольно. Даже не знаю, что сказать. А как Вы эти файлы создали?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov , самым обычным способом (New -> Folder), это проявляется не только у меня, но и у моих коллег у кого из ОС либо 10ка либо 8ка. Такое ощущение что это какой то баг в винде...

Comment: `New -> Folder` создает папку, а не файл

Comment: Сделал, как Вы сказали. Через контекстное меню `Создать - Текстовый документ`. Проблемы не вижу https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdTWs.png

Comment: Извиняюсь, не New -> Folder, а New -> Text Document. Похоже, что наши системы немного отличаются версиями. У меня 8.1 pro и английская http://dropmefiles.com/ZEAn8

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена!

Я менял региональные настройки и совершенно не принял во внимание региональный формат...

Проблема решилась после того как я поменял фомат Latvian (Latvia) на English (United Kingdom) : 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно проблема связана с тем, что в латышском алфавите не существует символа "Y" или "y" и система упорядочивает файлы/папки с имена которых начинаются с этого символа неправильно.

Спасибо всем кто откликнулся